# DistributeDefinitions is evaluating the definitions, and this only for a large number of definitions

Tags: bugs, parallelization, internals

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 13.0.1**

---

I am using *Mathematica* 11.3 and this seems to me to be a bug. I would like, if possible, some idea on a workaround.

Here is an example of a trivial code that works as expected:

```
nI = 10;
(NM[#] :=  Print[#] ) & /@ Range[1, nI];
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[NM];
```

That is, the code above generates no output, as expected.

Now, if the first line is changed to

```
nI = 20;
```

The same code leads to 40 lines being printed! From 1 to 20 two times.

For some reason, the `DistributeDefinitions` is forcing the definition of `NM` to be executed, and I do not want that to happen before I use `ParallelSubmit` and `WaitAll`. I tried this in two computers with *Mathematica* 11.3, any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: On my machine the behaviour changes from `nI`=17 to 18. If I look at `Definitions[NM]`, up to 17 it prints as `:=`-definitions, but above that it prints as `=`-definitions. Thus the core issue may be not with the parallel tools, but with how definitions are stored.

Comment: The reason appears to be that ``Language`ExtendedFullDefinition`` switches from using `RuleDelayed` to `Rule` after 18 down-values. This causes `DistributeDefinitions` to subsequently leak the evaluation.

Comment: Can you please report this to Wolfram support?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already sent an email to wolfram support, I am wating for their reply.

Comment: OK, let us know what they said. I expect responses may be slow due to the backlog built up during the holiday season.

Comment: I received an answer from Wolfram. They thanked the report and confirmed that the behaviour reported is not standard, specially considering that 17 and 18 are not very large numbers. I assume that they will try to correct it in a future version.

Comment: I confirm this is still a bug in M12

Comment: And still persisting in 13.1 :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### TL;DR;

Execute the following code to fix the problem:

```
DistributeDefinitions;
DownValues[Parallel`Protected`DistDefs] =
  DownValues[Parallel`Protected`DistDefs] /.
   HoldPattern[
     u : Parallel`Parallel`Private`updates =
      rhs_Language`ExtendedFullDefinition
     ] :>
    (
     u = Replace[
       rhs,
       defs : {(_HoldPattern -> _) ..} :> With[
         {res = RuleDelayed @@@ Unevaluated@defs},
         res /; True
         ],
       {4}
       ]
     );
```

### What does this do?

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` seems to change the return format at 18 down-values. This causes the subsequent manipulations of `DistributeDefinitions` on the returned `` Language`DefinitionList[…] `` expression to leak the evaluation of the definitions (as their r.h.s. are no longer protected by the `HoldRest` attribute of `RuleDelayed`).

The code above fixes this by wrapping the call to `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition `` (which happens in `` Parallel`Protected`DistDefs ``) with a piece of code that replaces definitions of the form `HoldPattern[…]->…` with `HoldPattern[…]:>…`, which prevents the evaluation leak.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I think this is a terrible Mathematica bug, since no "hack" should be necessary to demand the same behaviour from nI=17 to nI=18.  Although the code above works, I am worried if it will not have side effects. That is, can i simply insert it in my init.m file and always use it?

Comment: Yes, stuff like this is really annoying...  Regarding potential side effects: As far as I can tell, the fix should be completely safe: The only thing it does is to replace the definitions using `Rule` with ones using `RuleDelayed`, which is definitely supported (since it is what happens for less than 18 definitions). It is also a very localized modification, so it should only affect `DistributeDefinitions`, which is anyway half broken for more than 17 definitions. But in case you do encounter any issues, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with a larger number of definitions my recommendation is to disable the automatic distribution of definitions with

```
$DistributedContexts = None
```

and simply redo the definitions on all parallel kernels:

```
nI = 20;
(NM[#] := Print[#]) & /@ Range[1, nI];

With[{nI = nI}, ParallelEvaluate[(NM[#] := Print[#])& /@ Range[1, nI];]]
```

It's faster, too.

Comment: Roman, it took me a while to return to this issue. I am now in Mathematica 12.1.1. Perhaps your solution worked just right in a previous version, but in my current version it is not working. For the "nI=20" case, it prints everything. The other solution, from @LukasLang, still works.